# Jquery UI - multiple dialog boxes

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have initialized my jquery ui like this, I can get it working for one dialog box:

```
    <script>
// increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function() {
    $( "#treatment" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#treatment" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

However, I have a table and for one column, 'treatments' the user has to click on "more info" to find out more, so far I have coded it like this:

```
        foreach($foo['MedCond'] as $row)
    { 
    ?>

            <tr>
<td><b>Name:</b></td>
<td><b>Symptoms:</b></td>
<td><b>Treatment:</b></td>
<td><b>Effective From:</b></td>
<td><b>Effective To:</b></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Symptoms'];?> </td>
        <td><div id="treatment"><p><?php echo $row['Treatment'];?></p></div><button id="opener">More info</button></td> [...]
```

So for every row for treatments, there is a corresponding dialog open button, once they click on that, details about that particular treatment shows up. I have got this working for one, but it fails when more then one shares the same "treatment div".

How can I get this to work.

Cheers.

Comment: IDs must be unique. Try changing them to classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of Id. means use $( ".treatment" ).dialog and write div class="treatment". Same procedure for opener

Comment: Thanks. That worked, however, when I now click on "more opener", it opened every single treatment dialog, rather then the "more info" associated with that treatment only. I changed the button id , to button class , but that did not work. I guess it is because it cannot differentiate between the different treatments right?

Comment: You can loop your divs and match these you want to open


`$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( ".treatment" ).each (function ()
{
var myId=$(this).attr('id');
if(myId=="matchPattern")
{
$(this).dialog('open);
}
});
    });`

Comment: you have to set unique id for each treatment div (use any counter variable in the loop which set its id to treatment1,treatment2 and so on) . and set any attribute with button which contain treatment's div id let say <div class="opener" treatment="idoftreatment" ></div> and then check the attribute treatment in your function and open appropriate dialog box

Comment: thanks guys, so I should have it so that each div id=treatment basically has an int attached to it e.g. div id=treatment1 , div id =treatment 2 etc etc and that use Theodores solution to match which div id it is coming from...And yeah I guess div class = opener will not be an ID because it is not unique?